# all scripts unassigned after saving and closing Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Some reason my unity unassigned all scripts after I saved and closed. Yesterday it was working perfectly fine its after I saved and closed Unity and came back the next day all scripts were unassigned from all objects, variable were not working and has many errors in the terminal, I am using C# editor 2020.3.30f1 version of unity

Comment: _"unassigned all scripts"_ - what do you mean?

Comment: Consider using version control where if mistakes are made you can easily undo it.   https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the `.meta` files? They store the GUIDs of all assets, scripts etc which is what Unity uses for (de)serializing them and reconstructing your scenes and prefabs on restart

Comment: I am fairly new to unity and have never heard of  meta files so its probably highly likely that I dont have the meta files, how do I see if I have them and if I dont how do I get them back?